# Class with methods to retrieve data with Linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net, linq, classes

I think here is something wrong with code. I use a class with methods to get tenants from DB:

```
    public List<CrmTenant> GetAllTenants()
    {
        List<CrmTenant> tenantsList = new List<CrmTenant>();

        try
        {
            var crmTenants =
                 from tenant in context.CrmTenant
                 select tenant;

            if (crmTenants != null)
            {
                foreach (var tenant in crmTenants)
                {
                    tenantsList.Add(tenant);
                }
            }

            return tenantsList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Write("Failed to get all tenants from database.", "Exceptions", TraceEventType.Error, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets Tenant by name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public CrmTenant GetTenantByName(string tenantName)
    {
        CrmTenant crmTenant = null;

        try
        {
            crmTenant =
                 (from customerCrm in context.CrmTenant
                  where customerCrm.TenantName == tenantName
                  select customerCrm).Single();
            return crmTenant;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Write(String.Format("Failed to get tenant '{0}' from database.", tenantName), "Exceptions", TraceEventType.Error, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets tenant by Username.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public CrmTenant GetTenantByUserName(string userName)
    {
        CrmTenant crmTenant = null;

        try
        {
            crmTenant =
                 (from customerCrm in context.CrmTenant
                  where customerCrm.Username == userName
                  select customerCrm).Single();
            return crmTenant;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Write(String.Format("Failed to get tenant by username '{0}' from database.", userName), "Exceptions", TraceEventType.Error, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is call for methods

```
// get tenant
var crmTenant = CrmServiceHandlerFactory.GetInstance().Resolve<TenantManager>().GetTenantByUserName(userName);
```

I am new in programming, could you please help me to improve this code

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with your code?

Comment: Because I have ten methods like GetTenantByName GetTenantByUserName GetTenantBySize GetTenantByIce and so on... I doubt that it's a good style... Or i'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see some room for improvement:

1. Most importantly, you shouldn't hide exceptions like this. You should most likely let the exceptions bubble up and let the called decide what to do when an exception happens. And if you return `null`, it means you will either have to add `null` checks everywhere, or you will get `NullReferenceException` instead of the exception that actually caused the problem, which makes it harder to debug.
2. You don't need to add items into the list one by one, you can do it all at once using [`AddRange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx). Or even better, just use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx):

   ```
   return crmTenants.ToList();
   ```
3. This one is really minor, but the query `from tenant in context.CrmTenant select tenant` can be simplified to just `context.CrmTenant`, the LINQ doesn't do anything useful there.

#1 is by far the biggest issue, I think, because it shows an error in your design. #2 and #3 could just simplify your code a bit.